# Serialize an object with a List member

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xmlencoder

Given the following classes:

```
public class Container {
    private List<SomeData> list;
    // public getter & setter for list
}

public class SomeData {
    private String data;
   // public getter & setter for data
}
```

When I run the following code:

```
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

SomeData someData1 = new SomeData();
SomeData someData2 = new SomeData();

someData1.setData("data1");
someData2.setData("data2");

List<SomeData> data = new ArrayList<SomeData>();
data.add(someData1);
data.add(someData2);

Container container = new Container();
container.setList(data); 

FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("c:\test.xml");
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(os);
encoder.writeObject(container);
encoder.close();
```

When I review 'test.xml', there is only data for the container object, and nothing for the SomeData objects in the list (i.e. the strings "data1" & "data2"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<java version="1.6.0_22" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"> 
 <object class="Container"> 
  <void property="container"> 
   <object class="java.util.ArrayList"> 
    <void method="add"> 
     <object class="SomeData"/> 
    </void> 
    <void method="add"> 
     <object class="SomeData"/> 
    </void> 
   </object> 
  </void> 
 </object> 
</java>
```

How can I serialize 'container' and the SomeData objects stored in the list within 'container'?

Comment: Well, there is clearly something there, two instances of `SomeData`, but their fields are missing.

Comment: FYI: this works fine on my machine. Also, I think your code is inconsistent with example output.  In output you have property 'container' under Container, but in example code - the name of property is 'list'. So check your code for 'SomeData' fields setting.

Comment: Yea - I created the above example by hand, so there may be errors.  If it works fine on your machine, you mean you get the strings "data1" & "data2" in the xml?  Is the code exactly the same as above, or did you tweak it?

Comment: Oddly enough the code I wrote above does work, despite being almost identical to the original.  Time to break out the diff tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine for me as long as I provide getter for SomeData.data named according to the java beans naming convention:

```
SomeData.getData()
```

If I change the name of the getter, the serialization wont work.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did since the code I have is the same (save for name changes) as what I posted.  I basically rewrote the code and it worked!  Clearly I missed something.  Than-you for your feedback.